# How can I get the Mac address for Android devices in the Dart language 2023

Tags: android, flutter, dart, authentication, mac-address

I'm having a problem with Mac address identifying devices when I log in 2023.

I've tried all ways but I couldn't find a solution to this problem :
1- used mac_address .
2-
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

```
private  val CHANNEL = "com.example.getmac";

private  lateinit var channel: MethodChannel
override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

    channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,CHANNEL)

    channel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->

        if(call.method == "getMAC"){
            var mac =  getMacAddress();
            result.success(mac);
            Toast.makeText(this, mac, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }
    }
}

// a function that return mac
private fun getMacAddress(): String? {
    try {
        val all: List<NetworkInterface> =
            Collections.list<NetworkInterface>(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())
        for (nif in all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equals("wlan0", ignoreCase = true)) continue
            val macBytes: ByteArray = nif.getHardwareAddress() ?: return ""
            val res1 = StringBuilder()
            for (b in macBytes) {
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:", b))
            }
            if (res1.length > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length - 1)
            }
            return res1.toString()
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
    }
    return "02:00:00:00:00:00"

}
```

}

Comment: That sort of identifier has not been available to ordinary apps in a few years on modern versions of Android: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids?hl=en#mac-11-plus

Comment: This would seem to be an XY problem.  *Why* do you want the Mac address?  Are you trying to get a unique ID for the device?  Such actions are discouraged by the vendors, because it makes it hard to sell them a replacement device or the next better phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below plugin to get MAC Address of android or iOS.

**https://pub.dev/packages/mac_address**

I hope you will get what you are trying to get.

Comment: I tried to use this package, but I can't get the Mac address for devices with the latest version, so I need another way .

Comment: Did you try to add "android.permission.LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS" permission in android manifest?

Comment: I did not find this permission present in Android, but these permissions I added<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />